# Java EE Certificate-Based Mutual Authentication

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, websphere, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to  setup “Certificate-Based Mutual Authentication” in my Java EE application. My requirement outline as follows,
Deploying a web application (Java EE on IBM Webshpere) which is pulicly available in www, but access privileges were given only for authenticated clients via certificates.

Can someone provide me a sample code & setps that I have to follow to achieve my requirement.

Comment: The answers depends on the way how your envornment is set up and the way how you authenticate users. For example, if you use websphere build-in authentication, i belive, there should be built-in mechanizm to do this (although, i'm not an expert in websphere, but that's how it is usually with other verndors). Another possible challange is the way how your app server is connected to the web. Eg you may have apache in the front, in that case configurarion is different.

Comment: @ Stat : Thanks for the comment!
My expertise on this area is very poor & I’m doing an R&D to achieve the functionality, but I couldn’t find any specific tutorial to go ahead.  Can you explain the both ways which you have mentioned so then I could at least have an idea to which implementation steps that I have to follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stas mentioned you haven't stated anything about your application (what is the app server etc).

If your set up is WebSphere and you want to set up SSL mutual authentication, then this paper should give you a good idea:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_birk/0612_birk.html#sec1

The references in this article also contain good information and they should help you out.

Regarding Web Server, SSL hops would be between your App Server and the web server on the other end (and not to the WAS Server running). This does not change any configuration or the set up but you should be aware that your SSL communication would be till the web server and the web server might talk SSL to the back end application server and this depends on how it is set up.

If you provide additional information then folks here would be able to help.

HTH
Manglu